# How to make Cisco Webex Meeting desktop app work in Ubuntu?

Tags: wine, cisco

I have Ubuntu 16.04. I downloaded [Cisco Webex Meeting for Windows](https://www.webex.com/es/downloads.html) and installed via wine (version 5.6). There is yet no native Linux version. The app itself opens fine through wine. However, when I try to login using my credentials, it stays connecting forever. When I run the app through the terminal, [this is the output](https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/3N9tdBt8cW/). Nothing I can really understand. I don't see any entry on WineHQ about this software.

On the one hand it seems like there might be a problem with the internet through wine. However, if I type in a wrong password, the app tells me so. I doubt the credentials are embedded in the client itself so I imagine the app is connected to the Cisco server. The problem seems to be elsewhere. I've looked at two related posts in this forum ([here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/276358/how-do-i-get-cisco-webex-working-under-debian-7-64bit) and [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/108032/can-not-use-webex-in-centos-6-5-fedora-18-and-20)) but they seem to focus on entering a meeting through the website rather than through the desktop app (and both posts are quite old).

Would any of you have an idea what's going on?

Comment: Just a thought: Do you have a clean wine prefix? Is there maybe something the app needs like dotnet or similar?

Comment: @Jan It's not clean. I have several apps installed. dotnet 4.0, vcrun 2003, 2012, 2013, wininet, etc. How could I know what is required? The [official description for windows](https://help.webex.com/en-us/1vek5r/Webex-Meetings-System-Requirements-and-Cross-Platform-Information#reference_D9B64C287DA6490784F958C7B88BBC8F) is not very precise, except that at least Windows 7 is required.